# results for a query in web search

Tags: search-engine

how do i make sure that given a query i get results as only web pages(i.e., .html,.htm) and not any other formats (i.e., pdf, ppt, doc)

Answer (score 0):

On google the following syntax can be used.

searchterm -filetype:pdf -filetype:ppt -filetype:doc